# Does not populate array with item before breaking out of loop

Tags: javascript

I am having an issue with a every function I am using and not sure if I have my logic correct. What I was hoping was to go through each 'event' and if the ready field is 'true', push that event into the array then break out of the loop. If the ready field is false, then stay in the loop and continue.

What seems to happen is that on the first event, if ready is false, it seems to come out of the loop and proceed with the next part of the code. As there is nothing in the array as it doesn't fit the criteria, I get an undefined and then later on my code breaks because of it.

What am I doing incorrect that it's unable to complete the for each loop so it looks for a ready true event first before proceeding?

```
function createData(list) {

  const events = JSON.parse(list).data.events;
  let readyEvent = [];

  events.every((event) => {
    console.log("READY", event.ready);
    if (event.ready == "true") {
      readyEvent.push(event);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });

  console.log("READY EVENTS", readyEvent[0]); //this comes back undefined as first event had ready status as false

  const selectedEvent = readyEvent[0];

  console.log("EVENT PICKED", selectedEvent); //picks undefined event

...

}
```

Example list:

```
"data":{
"events": {
    [
    "eventid": "3030330",
    "ready": "true"
    ],
    [
    "eventid": "3030331",
    "ready": "true"
    ],
    [
    "eventid": "3030332",
    "ready": "true"
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: What does `list` look like? In particular, `event.ready == "true"` looks suspect. Is `ready` really a string? What do you see when you step through the code with [the debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/)?

Comment: *"it's unable to complete the for each loop"* There is no *for each* loop, but a misused `.every()`

Comment: is `event.ready` really a string?

Comment: FWIW, while you *can* use `every` for a loop you break out of when a condition is (not) met, in modern code it's more idiomatic to simply use `for (const event of events)` and `break;` when you want to stop looping.

Comment: [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) would be a better candidate

Comment: So it looks like `ready:"true"` or `ready:"false"`

Comment: @BruceyBandit - Please update the question with an example of `list`. rather than describing it. Ideally, provide a **runnable** example of the problem using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: @Cid - Quite. I hadn't yet clocked that it's looking for a single element and not doing anything else.

Comment: But even without seeing `list`, looking at the code, if the first element doesn't match the condition, your code will stop looking (since returning `false` from an `every` callback stops its iteration of the array). So that's probably the problem. Switching to `find` as Cid suggested would fix it: `const selectedEvent = events.find((event) => event.ready === "true");` (if `ready` is really a string as you've indicated). If that's the problem, I suggest just deleting the question. See [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/) and several others.

Comment: List is updated. Just giving it a go TJ

Comment: `{"events": { [ … ] } }` is a syntax error. What does your data actually look like? Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @Bergi - I had to modify the data as it's confidential data

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you very much, the find method worked

Comment: @BruceyBandit You don't have to post the actual data, but you have to post syntactically valid data that lets us actually reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for one thing, your data set is egregiously wrong.  I think you want:

```
{
    "data":{
    "events": 
    [{
        "eventid": "3030330",
        "ready": "true"
    },
     {
         "eventid": "3030331",
         "ready": "true"
     },
     {
         "eventid": "3030332",
         "ready": "true"
     }]
    }
}
```

Running with that data set, your code “works”, but you still should not write it that way.

You are operating under the assumption that `every()` is implemented the way that *you* would write it: it iterates through the list left to right, stopping on the first failure.  That is not the definition of `every()`.

As has been pointed out in the comment, you are trying to re-implement `find()`.  Just use `find()`:

```
const selectedEvent = events.find((event) => event.ready === "true");
```

or even

```
const selectedEvent = events.find(({ ready }) => ready === "true");
```

Not only is that 90% fewer lines of code, it does not fail if the library implementer decides to, for example, parallelize the library.